# Can't access photos on Nexus device

Tags: photos, windows, nexus

I have connected my phone (Nexus) to my windows 10 computer. I have entered the pin number on the phone and the driver for the phone is installed on the computer. The device shows up on Windows Explorer but the folder is empty so I can not access my photos. Any ideas?

Comment: Which Nexus and which Android version?

Comment: Android Version 7 and Nexus version 5x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 6.0 and above you have to select USB connection type on your phone after you attached a computer or other device because the default USB connection type is charging.

You can do that when you plugged in your phone to your computer pull the phone's notification bar and tap on the appearing notification, something like this: `USB for charging` and select the desired USB connection type - in your case: File transfer (aka `MTP`).

There is a way to set the default USB connection type to MTP. You should enable `Developer options` on your device and in it search `Select USB Configuration` and set it to `MTP`.